# wpf UI not updating on data context change

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, datacontext

I am developing and wpf app and in which I need to update data on basis of click on button. I tried to update in code behind but it did not work so I used datacontext but still no use. I saw various solutions and have used mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger but it does not work.

```
<Grid DataContext="{Binding Dashboard, Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
//Content
</Grid>
```

In cs file

```
public ViewModels.DashboardVM _DashVM = new ViewModels.DashboardVM();

async private void DashboardPage_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                await _DashVM.GetDashboardData();
                this.DataContext = _DashVM;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.Write(ex.Message);
            }
        }
```

and changing data context here

```
async private void StoresList_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                var item = (sender as ListView).SelectedItem as Models.StoresLM;
                if(item!=null)
                {
                    Properties.Settings.Default.StoreId = item.id;
                    Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
                    await _DashVM.GetDashboardData();

                    this.DataContext = _DashVM;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.Write(ex.Message);
            }
        }
```

my View Model is

```
public class DashboardVM : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private Models.DashboardM _dashboard;
    public Models.DashboardM Dashboard
    {
        get { return _dashboard; }
        set { _dashboard = value; RaisePropertyChanged("Dashboard"); }
    }

    private void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    public static event EventHandler<Boolean> IsLoading = delegate { };

    async public Task<Boolean> GetDashboardData()
    {
        try
        {
            if (InternetTools.IsNetworkConnected())
            {
                IsLoading(this, true);
                var storeId = Convert.ToString(Properties.Settings.Default.StoreId);
                var Response = await new WebServiceUtility().PostRequest(string.Format(StringUtility.DashboardApi, Convert.ToString(Properties.Settings.Default.StoreId)), new[] { new KeyValuePair<string, string>("api_key", "dbjh") });
                if (Response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    var DashboardData = await Response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                    var jsonObject = Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject.Parse(DashboardData);
                    if (Convert.ToString(jsonObject["success"]).IndexOf("True", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0)
                    {
                        var DashObject = jsonObject.ToObject<Models.DashboardM>();
                        Properties.Settings.Default.Currency = DashObject.data.store.currency.StartsWith("&") ? System.Net.WebUtility.HtmlDecode(DashObject.data.store.currency) : System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Unescape(DashObject.data.store.currency);
                        DashObject.data.store.currency = StringUtility.Currency;
                        Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
                        Dashboard = null;
                        Dashboard = DashObject;
                    }
                }
            }
            else
                NotificationUtility.ShowErrorMessage(NotificationUtility.MsgType.InternetError);
        }
        catch
        {

        }
        IsLoading(this, false);
        return true;
    }
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged = delegate { };
}
```

Can anybody help?

Comment: so, you have an async model that might change. It'll notify if you change the WHOLE object, but not if you change things INSIDE it. Are the objects inside it raising notifications as well ?

Comment: no objects inside are not raising notifications. Actually I need 5 properties to change inside this others are not needed yet.

Comment: try raising notifications there, and i would also try without the async on the changing method, but i'm not sure if it's related or not.

Comment: Instead of changing DataContext, update the properties inside the DataContext

Comment: If you can load your viewmodel asynchronously, why wait until *after* your view is loaded?  Do them at the same time.

Comment: Because till data is updated if user performs any action then it might change the actual flow desired. It can create inconsistency.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve the problem by editing the code. It was not getting notified due to reassigning of object. I don't know the reason but I just changed this code

```
async private void StoresList_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            var item = (sender as ListView).SelectedItem as Models.StoresLM;
            if(item!=null)
            {
                Properties.Settings.Default.StoreId = item.id;
                Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
                await _DashVM.GetDashboardData();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.Write(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

Hope it helps somebody like me.